# Move images from a image field to another field

Tags: 8

Some months ago I developed a D8 based website for a customer with an image field with multiple values, displayed as a [Bootstrap Basic Image Gallery](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_basic_image_gallery).

Now, my customer has changed his mind so now he wants to set the possibility to insert either an image or a video, so I decided to use [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) to let him choose if he wants an Image or an [embed Video](https://www.drupal.org/project/video_embed_field).

The problem is that the customer has over 1000 nodes with an average of 3-4 images per node, so if I change the field to a Paragraph one, the images previously saved in the Image field are not moving to the Paragraph field.

Is there a way to "migrate" the images from an Image field to a Paragraph referenced Image field?

P.S: As you may understand, re-uploading the images again might be, if I can say, a PITA

Comment: The answer is: Yes. And in my opinion the "best" would be you implement a custom form that only contains a button you can trigger manually, where you use a batch process in the submit function to do what you want programmatically. Your question must actually be split into at least three separate questions: How to programmatically load node and get image field value (file ID), how to programmatically create paragraphs and populate fields in it, and how to process data in a batch to prevent time-out. Alternatively try Drupal's Migrate API but I've zero experience on that.

Comment: Why not simply adding another field for the video and then switch the display accordingly? Maybe with a pseudo field.

Comment: Why would it be necessary to use paragraphs? Is there an issue stopping you from just adding another field for videos? There are many ways you can migrate data from one field to another but what's best depends on the situation. Depending on what your end goal is it might be overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO, MineDoodler!

A little bit ago I found the same problem, so I developed this piece of code. (Note that I started a little bit ago with developing, it is possible to achieve this easier).

Read the comments to understand the code.

```php
use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use \Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph;
use \Drupal\file\Entity\File;


function migrateImages() {
  // Get all products
  $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
  $query->condition('status', 1);
  $query->condition('type', 'productos');
  $nids = $query->execute();

  $allNids = [];

  // In my case, i had a keyed array (First element was [213] => "157") so I turned into ([0] => "157")
  foreach ($nids as $nid) {
    $allNids[] = $nid;
  }

  // Go through every node
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($nids); $i++) {
    $nodeID = $allNids[$i];

    // Load node.
    $node = Node::load($nodeID);

    // Get current paragraphs (if already has any).
    $current = $node->get('field_prod_media')->getValue();

    // Go through every image this node has.
    foreach ($node->field_prod_img as $item) {
      // Create new paragraph
      $paragraph = Paragraph::create(['type' => 'YOUR_PARAGRAPH_TYPE']);

      // Load image
      $file = File::load($item->target_id);

      // Save image
      $paragraph->set('IMAGE_FIELD_IN_PARAGRAPH', $file);

      // Force the new "alt". I've done this because it wasn't saving the alt.
      $paragraph->field_img->alt = $item->alt;
      
      // Check if it's new and save it.
      $paragraph->isNew();
      $paragraph->save();
      
      // Add to the current paragraphs the new one.
      $current[] = array(
        'target_id' => $paragraph->id(),
        'target_revision_id' => $paragraph->getRevisionId(),
      );
    }
    
    // Set again all paragraphs, with the new ones.
    $node->set('field_prod_media', $current);
    $node->save();
    dpm("node ".$node->label()." has been saved!");
  }
}
```

Took the idea from #7 in [this post](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/2707017#comment-11872624) and developed by my knowledge.

I forgot to mention that this code was executed in the [Devel PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_php), in the [Devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel).

Comment: I've tried it and worked as expected! Note you forgot the `dpm` at the end, just saying. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: It is just a friendly reminder that your nodes were updated!